# how to add icon and title to the browser tab using javascript

Tags: javascript, ember.js

i have to show the content in the other browsing tab. the other browsing tab is coming as an untitled tab. I have used window.open to get one more browsing tab.
I want to display the head icon and the title to the tab. how to display icon and title.

my code>>

```
var policy =  window.open("", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
policy.document.write("<p>result</p>");
```

i have to add icon and title to this policy tab.

Comment: Include favicon settings and `<title>` in the HTML you pass to the window.

Comment: how can i add using javascript

Comment: You can use `document.title = 'new title'` to change the title, but it won't reflect for SEO.

Comment: title i have added. but how to add icon to the new tab. i to pass <link> tag using javascript

Comment: `policy.document.head.appendChild(linkElement)`.

Comment: var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.type = 'image/x-icon';
    link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
    link.href = 'https://icon.favicon.png';
    policy.document.head.appendChild(link);    i have written this code but icon is not appearing